# How to truncate a join table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, truncate

To truncate an ActiveRecord table, I can do

```
Category.destroy_all
```

or

```
Post.destroy_all
```

How does one go about truncating a `categories_post` table?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For a true `TRUNCATE`, you can use `execute` to run the raw SQL.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name}")
```

Your examples using models weren't doing true `TRUNCATE` queries.

- `destroy_all` does not `TRUNCATE` a table. It "destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method" ([link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class)).
- `delete_all` is closer - it ignores callbacks - but still not a `TRUNCATE`.

Using the `execute` method deletes the rows from the database without creating any model instances.

Also, an actual `TRUNCATE` query, at least in MySQL, will reset the auto-increment on the primary key, so that the next record you insert will have id of 1.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your join table is called categories_posts. CategoryPost.destroy_all should work, if not, maybe you need to specify the table name in the model (CategoryPost)

```
set_table_name "categories_posts"
```

Update, there isn't a CategoryPost model, so it should be created:

```
class CategoryPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "categories_posts"
end
```

Comment: join tables don't have an associated model. e.g., `CategoryPost`